# storing curl output to a variable is working in linux but not through Jenkins

Tags: shell, curl

I have a script that works well in Linux and Mac. But when I tried to execute the same script using Jenkins, not getting any output.

```
identifier=$(curl --location --request GET 'https://bigmachines.com/rest/v9/migrationPackages' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic cmFodWxzYWhuaTpIQ0xUZWNoQDEy' | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; RS="," }; { if ($2 == "identifier") {print $4} }')
echo step1 $identifier
```

This provides the value for `$identifier`
but If I execute the same from the Jenkins shell prompt, I am not getting any values for `$identifier`
Pls let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample pipeline job, that will capture the output of curl command in a variable and display it:

```yaml
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        
        stage('Display contents of curl') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def response = sh(script: "curl -i https://api.github.com/users/souravatta?url | awk '/login/ {print}'", returnStdout: true)
                    
                    echo "${response}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Replace the contents of `curl` with your curl command and try.